# Largest value of a third order determinant whose elements are 0 or 1

Tags: permutations, combinations, determinant

Find the Largest value of a third order determinant whose elements are 0 or 1.

My try:
\begin{vmatrix} a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1} \\a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2} \\ a_{3} & b_{3} & c_{3}  \end{vmatrix}
I opened the determinant, and concluded that the value of detrminant cannot exceed 3. I have no idea what to do next. Please help me.

Comment: You haven't shown us what you've done already.  How can we know what you should do next (if anything)?

Comment: I already wrote just open the determinant and all the positive terms can be one and negative terms to be zero, and then we conclude it cant exceed 3.I advise to plz work it urself, its really tough to type it in latex.

Comment: Interesting problem which can be generalized to an $nxn$-matrix (of zeroes and ones). It seems that the maximum is $n-1$. I have tested the case $n=4$ by brute force.

Comment: No, my conjecture was false. For $n=5$ the maximum of the determinant is $5$. Hence the generalized question remains open.

Comment: @ Vasanth Bhaskara  I have just learned that this is a standard problem http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardsMaximumDeterminantProblem.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\begin{vmatrix} a_{1} & b_{1} & c_{1} \\a_{2} & b_{2} & c_{2} \\ a_{3} & b_{3} & c_{3}  \end{vmatrix}=a_1b_2c_3+b_1c_2a_3+c_1a_2b_3-a_3b_2c_1-b_3c_2a_1-c_3a_2b_1.$$

Each of these terms are either $0$ or $1$ (depending on the entries chosen to be $1$ or $0$). So to maximize *one may want to choose* the entries with positive terms becoming $1$ and the negative terms becoming $0$. However that is NOT possible because then all entries become $1$ and the determinant takes on the value $0$. So the **maximum value cannot be $3$**.

Since we cannot have all the positive terms be $1$ (without having the negative terms also being equal to $1$) so we try to see if we can have two of the positive terms as $1$.

Observe that we can have the following: 
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & c_{1} \\a_{2} & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & b_{3} & 1  \end{vmatrix}=1+1+c_1a_2b_3-c_1-b_3-a_2.$$

But now to maximize we need to have $c_1=a_2=b_3=0$. This gives the maximum value of the determinant to be $2$.

---

It might be also good to look at the determinant as volume of the parallelepiped to convince yourself with the validity of the result.

Comment: Nice reasoning. I know that determinant is the factor by which the volume of a unit cube formed by basis vectors change during a linear transformation. However I couldn't see this result. Any guidance?